# Who are the companions of the elephant mentioned in Surah Al-Fil?

Tags: tafseer, islamic-events

Who are the companions of the elephant mentioned in Surah Al-Fil (The Elephant), what was their treacherous plan and how did it go astray?

Answer (score 4):

The companions of the elephant refer to the army of Abraha, so-called because it included a number of war elephants.  He felt slighted by the Quraysh, and planned to exact revenge by destroying the kaaba.

He didn't succeed.

Comment: he felt because kaaba more popular than his site.

Answer (score -2):

The Madain Project explains the companions or the people of the elephant in the following passage; I have added the link to the article as well.

> The Companions of the Elephant (أصحاب الفيل) are a group of people whose story is recounted in the chapter of the Quran named "The Elephant
> Companions of the Elephant are referred to in verse (105:1) of chapter (105) sūrat al-fīl (The Elephant): (أَلَمْ تَرَ كَيْفَ فَعَلَ رَبُّكَ بِأَصْحَابِ الْفِيلِ)
> Translation: Have you not considered, [O Muhammad], how your Lord dealt with the companions of the elephant?"

Source: https://madainproject.com/companions_of_the_elephant